# Passing variables for media queries and rendering css in styled components?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

im trying to write a more robust version of media queries in styled components.

I basically have a breakpoints file defined, i pass the respective breakpoint into another file which is rendered here:

```
const setMq = breakpoints => {
    return css` @media (min-width: ${breakpoints.from / 16}em) and (max-width: ${breakpoints.until / 16}em) {}`
};
```

Then in my actual styled component im trying to call it, but for whatever reason i cannot get the new colour of "blue" to render?

```
const ButtonStyled = styled.button`
    color: red;

    ${(setMq({
        from: breakpoints.xs,
        until: breakpoints.l,
     }),
     `
        color: blue;
    `)};
`;
```

Comment: Can you console log the setMq result?

Comment: Yes, so i basically returns a css array: ["@media only screen and (min-width:", "36", "em) and (max-width:", "62", "em){}"]. Im guessing i maybe need to return just the media query line without the opening and closing {}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, anyone else needing the solution, i needed to change my main "function" to not output as an array but return as as string:

```
const setMq = breakpoints => {
return style => 
    `@media only screen and (min-width: ${breakpoints.from / 16}em) and (max-width: ${breakpoints.until / 16}em) { ${style} }`;
};
```

and then called with:

```
const ButtonStyled = styled.button`
color: red;

${setMq({
    from: breakpoints.xs,
    until: breakpoints.l,
    })`color: blue;`};
`;

export { ButtonStyled };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using styled-system with styled-components, and I really recommend it. I can define the breakpoints(media queries) and its styles in the global `theme.ts` file rather than defining it individually, and it works well(also re-usable across the components).
For example, I have

```
...
grid: {
        breakpoints: [375, 768, 1200],
        maxWidth: 1440,
    },
...
```

in my theme.ts file and font-size changes depends on screen size. Such as

```
error: {
    fontSize: [11, 11, 14],
    fontWeight: "regular",
    lineHeight: ["14px", "14px", "18px"],
    fontFamily: "PT Sans, sans-serif",
    color: "#FF2222",
},
```

I think in your case, you can apply something similar like

```
color: ['red', 'red', 'blue']
```

There is an npm library for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components-breakpoint
but also you can just use styled-system's default breakpoint for responsiveness https://styled-system.com/responsive-styles

Comment: Thank you for replying! So im guessing my answer will be a combination of a few of these and in the links you provided. 

The nature of the company i work for means they only want a breakpoint value to be variable. So i need to almost call a "mixin" within my styled component every time and then pass whatever css i need.

Comment: oh yes, calling breakpoints as variable shouldn't be an issue.  I would imagine that the breakpoints are shared across the component and not different for each individual component.